# How does shuffle=True affect a Keras model with two inputs?

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, shuffle

Good afternoon,

I have a Keras model that has two inputs into the model. The inputs get processed through an encoding layer, and then the output gets concatenated in the next layer.

For the .fit method, there's a parameter called "shuffle" which I normally leave on True, but I'm a little unsure in this scenario.

The inputs depend on one another. In fact, the second input is a complement to the first input in a particular feature. Would setting shuffle=True in this case be a bad idea?

Let's say the feature I'm focused on has a True or False value. If Input1 has a value of "True" for this feature, I would want to have an input as "False" for Input2.

If I set shuffle to True, would I end up with a situation where I would get "True" - "True" as inputs into the network?

Answer (score 0):

### Answer to the shuffle argument

Shuffle will not have bad influence on this particular case. The arrays will be get shuffled together. For example assume you have the following two arrays to the network.

```py
x1 = np.array([19,  0, 17, 15,  9, 15, 10,  4, 18,  3, 18,  8, 12, 11,  8, 12, 10,
        9, 11,  8])
x2 = np.array([18, 13,  2, 17, 14,  0,  9, 15,  1,  1,  5,  7, 14,  1, 13, 10, 12,
       12,  9, 16])
```

This two arrays can be shuffled together by, first generating the shuffled indices and then indexing each array by the shuffled indices.

```py
indices = np.arange(x1.shape[0])
np.random.seed(123)
x1 = x1[indices]

x2 = x2[indices]
print(x1)
# [ 8 15  9  9 18  4  8 12 19 12 10  3  8 18 15  0 10 11 17 11]
print(x2)
# [13  0 14 12  1 15 16 14 18 10 12  1  7  5 17 13  9  9  2  1]
```

As it can be seen in the above `print`s output, the relative positions of the data points is preserved. E.g 8 in `x1` and `13` in x2`were both at index`14`. But after shuffling both have moved to index 0. Keras uses the same approach when the shuffle argument is passed.

In keras the shuffling can be done on either entire training dataset or on batch level. The official documentation states:

> Boolean (whether to shuffle the training data before each epoch) or str (for 'batch'). This argument is ignored when x is a generator. 'batch' is a special option for dealing with the limitations of HDF5 data; it shuffles in batch-sized chunks. Has no effect when steps_per_epoch is not None.

### Discussion on the dependence of the inputs

One of the assumptions of the inputs to feed forward neural networks is they are independent. In your case however you have two inputs where the second input depends on the first input. This violates the assumption of independence. One possible solution is using neural networks that assumes dependence among the inputs. For example Recurrent Neural Networks(RNN) are good choice for such problems.